# Deserializing XML to builders using target class annotations

Tags: java, xml, builder

Is there any tool or library that serializes XML to builders by base object's annotations or scheme?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by builders but there are several libraries that handle class marshaling and unmarshaling between Java classes and XML. You can use the reference implementation of [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) or the widely used alternative [JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/) . If you want a simpler library, maybe [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) will suffice for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By builders I meant autogenerated classes that do not present in your classpath at development time, maybe only as an API; exist as a "cached version" of your xml in runtime; and asked each time you need any actual object structure that you defined in xml notation. I wondered if any ready solution exists. But now I came to another solution, which i stick with - I will map my classes as is (into jaxb or another notation) and add copy() method to the hierarchy top-level class. In this way my classes will be builders by themselves.